# How can I determine the type of a packed array?

Tags: undocumented, packed-arrays

[Packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) can be of type `Integer`, `Real` or `Complex`.  Knowing that an array `arr` is packed, how can I efficiently determine its type?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We can use one of several ways. First, let us create some test data:

```
arr = Range[10]; (* this is an Integer packed array *)
unpacked = {1, 2, 3} (* this is an Integer array that is NOT packed *)
```

---

Since Mathematica 10.4, **`` Internal`PackedArrayType ``** directly returns the type:

```
Internal`PackedArrayType[arr]
(* Integer *)

Internal`PackedArrayType[unpacked]
(* $Failed *)
```

---

[**`` Developer`PackedArrayQ ``**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/PackedArrayQ.html) has a second argument, which is the type of the array.  This way we can test both for the type and "packedness" at the same time.

```
Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr, Integer]
(* True *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ[arr, Real]
(* False *)

Developer`PackedArrayQ[unpacked, Integer]
(* False *)
```

This function is useful in specializing functions for processing packed array of various types, e.g. to dispatch to the appropriate LibraryLink function.  A third argument allows testing for the array depth as well.

---

To get the type directly in versions of Mathematica prior to 10.4, without testing for each possible type using `PackedArrayQ`, we can extract an element and check its head:

```
packedArrayType[arr_?Developer`PackedArrayQ] := Head@Extract[arr, Table[1, {ArrayDepth[arr]}]]
packedArrayType[___] := $Failed
```

This is roughly what `` NDSolve`FEM`PackedArrayType `` does, which confirms to me that this is the appropriate way.  In a package, I would define `packedArrayType` in a version-dependent manner as

```
If[$VersionNumber >= 10.4, 
  packedArrayType = Internal`PackedArrayType,
  packedArrayType[...] := (* manual method from above *)
]
```

Answer (score 10):

There's another useful function for this kind of thing

```
arr = RandomReal[1, 10^8];
Developer`PackedArrayForm[arr]
```

> ```
> "PackedArray"[Real, "<" 100000000 ">"]
> ```

The drawback is that this is for display purposes only, <s>it doesn't seem to be possible to extract the `Real` from this.</s>

on second thoughts, this seems to work:

```
Developer`PackedArrayForm[Range[10]] // ToBoxes // MakeExpression // #[[1, 1]] &
```

> ```
> Integer
> ```

Comment: That's why I expected that there has to be a way to determine the type. Only when I saw ``NDSolve`FEM`PackedArrayType`` was I finally convinced that there is not (for M < 10.4).

Comment: @Szabolcs hacky approach, but see update.